# about determinant relation in block matrix with non square blocks

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

if $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $B$ is an $n\times m$ matrix  prove that

$$\det \left( \begin{bmatrix} O &A \\-B & I \end{bmatrix} \right)=\det(AB)$$

tried many thing such as getting it to triangle form but I could not
maybe you can, or can give alternative answer

Answer (score 2):

You can get it into triangular form  by means of column operations. Or look at it this way:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
O & A\\
-B & I
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
I & O\\
B & I
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
AB & A\\
O & I
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and taking determinants gives the result.